# Run second grep relative to first find

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to find a specific string in a text, and then base on the position of the string, find a second string that is the closes to it (backwards) and print the information. I've got the following:

```
<tile x="143" y="43" z="7">
<item id="2656"/>
<item id="2111" count="5"/>
<item id="2194"/>
<item id="2205"/>
<item id="2400"/>
</tile>

<tile x="143" y="44" z="7">
<item id="2656"/>
<item id="2111" count="5"/>
<item id="2194"/>
<item id="2205"/>
</tile>

<tile x="143" y="45" z="7">
<item id="2656"/>
<item id="2111" count="5"/>
<item id="2194"/>
<item id="2205"/>    
</tile>

<tile x="144" y="43" z="7">
<item id="2656"/>
<item id="2194"/>
<item id="2111" count="5"/>
<item id="2506" special_description="something something something (Arm:12) [Test]"/>
<item id="2194"/>
<item id="2216"/>
<item id="2400"/>
</tile>

<tile x="144" y="44" z="7">
<item id="2656"/>
<item id="2111" count="5"/>
<item id="2194"/>
<item id="2418"/>
<item id="2216"/>
<item id="2431"/>
</tile>

<tile x="144" y="45" z="7">
<item id="2656"/>
<item id="2658"/>
<item id="2111" count="5"/>
<item id="2506" special_description="something something (Arm:12) [Whatever]"/>
<item id="2194"/>
<item id="2216"/>
</tile>

<tile x="146" y="43" z="7">
<item id="1738"/>
<item id="1738"/>
<item id="1738"/>
<item id="2160" count="50"/>
<item id="2183"/>
<item id="2127"/>
<item id="2127"/>
<item id="2205"/>
<item id="2506"/>
<item id="2127"/>
</tile>
```

The text is all one line, I've split it in separate lines for it to be easier to look through. Originally it looks like this:

```
<tile x="143" y="43" z="7"><item id="2656"/><item id="2111" count="5"/><item id="2194"/><item id="2205"/><item id="2400"/></tile><tile x="143" y="44" z="7">...
```

Let's say I'm looking for 2 specific item id's - 2506 and 2418. I've found 2506 in the fourth tile block using grep, now I want to see what tile coordinates it has:

I've found this:

```
<item id="2506" special_description="something something something (Arm:12) [Test]"/>
```

and right above it I find this:

```
<tile x="144" y="43" z="7">
```

How would I be able to extract the tile information for all those, get the special description if it exists and generate a log?

Ideally it would look like this (but the output is not too important as long as I get all the information extracted):

```
2506:
144,43,7 | [Test]
144,45,7 | [Whatever]
146,43,7 | 

2418:
144,44,7 |
```

Ideally if someone could get me a ready solution, it'd be much appreciated, but just a helpful pointer would be sufficient!

Comment: Sounds like your best bet is with an xml parser of some sort instead of grep/awk.

Comment: The purpose of XML is to provide the type of semantic information you are asking about. Don't ask about how to manipulate the *text*; ask about how to process the *data*. Your question is really: "How do I get the `x` and `y` attributes of the `tile` element(s) which contains an `item` element with an `id` attribute equal to 2506"

Comment: Thanks guys, any recommendations for a tool that would get the job done?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

this may get you started...

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= '/id="2506"/{print $1}' file

<tile x="144" y="43" z="7">
<tile x="144" y="45" z="7">
<tile x="146" y="43" z="7">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to write a script to do this.  Here is the pseudo code:

```
for all lines in file do {
  if line =~ /pattern1/ {
    match1 = line
  }
  elsif line =~ /pattern2/ {
   echo line, match1
  }
}
```